# Google signin not working in safari private mode

Tags: javascript, safari, google-openid, google-signin

I've included Google signin in my webapp using [this docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) but when I try to load the site from Safari in private mode I always get following error in console

```
QuotaExceededError: DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota.
setItem4187590794-idpiframe.js:19:293
g4187590794-idpiframe.js:19:293
Ea4187590794-idpiframe.js:30
(funzione anonima)4187590794-idpiframe.js:33
onreadystatechange4187590794-idpiframe.js:11:477
```

I know that safari in private mode doesn't allow to write in `localStorage` but isn't there any workaround to let google signin work also in private mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't let localStorage/sessionStorage setItem throw errors in Safari Private Browsing Mode

Have a look at this:
https://gist.github.com/philfreo/68ea3cd980d72383c951

```
// Safari, in Private Browsing Mode, looks like it supports localStorage but all calls to setItem
// throw QuotaExceededError. We're going to detect this and just silently drop any calls to setItem
// to avoid the entire page breaking, without having to do a check at each usage of Storage.
if (typeof localStorage === 'object') {
    try {
        localStorage.setItem('localStorage', 1);
        localStorage.removeItem('localStorage');
    } catch (e) {
        Storage.prototype._setItem = Storage.prototype.setItem;
        Storage.prototype.setItem = function() {};
        alert('Your web browser does not support storing settings locally. In Safari, the most common cause of this is using "Private Browsing Mode". Some settings may not save or some features may not work properly for you.');
    }
}
```

Safari Private Browsing is known to cause such issues. The easiest way to fix this, is to alter the function localStorage.

Try this

```
function isLocalStorageNameSupported() 
{
    var testKey = 'theTestKey', storage = window.sessionStorage;
    try 
    {
        storage.setItem(testKey, '1');
        storage.removeItem(testKey);
        return localStorageName in win && win[localStorageName];
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can find a detailed documentation and other solutions here: https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/issues/42

Comment: The problem is inside Google JS that's not loaded correctly and Google Signin doesn't work. I've resolved not loading that JS if localStorage is not available

Comment: @GUL If you would ... what did you do about Google Sign-In without  Google JS API? If you have your code on Git or something, that would be fine. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't show the entire code but I can explain what I do. If the localStorage is not available I don't load Google JS API. To test if localStorage is available, I just try to write a value, if it throws an exception than it's not available